# Azure Mobile App Service InsertAsync Error For XamarinForms

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am currently building a cross-platform mobile app using XamarinForms and an Azure Mobile app on the backend and I'm running into an issue with the InsertAsync function. Whenever I call it, it successfully inserts the data into my table but immediately throws an InvalidOperation exception with the message " Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric". Any idea why its throwing this exception/any possible fixes?

My client side model(matches the server side table):

```
public class Bet
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "endDate")]
    public int endDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Payout1")]
    public string Payout1 { get; set; }

    [Version]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="version")]
    public byte[] version { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "createdAt")]
    public DateTime? createdAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "updatedAt")]
    public DateTime? updatedAt { get; set; }
```

the offending code:

```
    public async void addBet(Bet myBet, List<UserBet> myUserBets)
    {
        IMobileServiceTable<Bet> betTable = client.GetTable<Bet>();

        myBet.ID = null;
        await betTable.InsertAsync(myBet);
    }
```

My table:

**Name Type IS Index**

id          String    true

Name        String    false

endDate     Number    false

Description String    false

Payout1     String    false

version     Version   false

createdAt   Date      false

updatedAt   Date      false

deleted     Boolean   false

Comment: It looks like a type mismatch. Are you sure you're correctly matching types? My guesses are payout or ID being incorrect, not having any idea about your DB schema.

Comment: Added the DB schema, any ideas?

Comment: 1.I've never seen "Number" type and can't seem to find any documentation on it (in SQL) - so I think you meant "Numeric". 
2. I would have expected a column labeled "End Date" to contain a Date (or DateTime) type. 
3. Your capitalization is inconsistent, and depending on your server settings, it could cause issues. 
4. Payout is a string? 

--------- 

That being said, your error is a type mismatch; somewhere a string (or something we think looks like a string- nvarchar ) is being converted to a number and it's causing problems. I'd look at #4 above first.

Comment: 1. It actually is listed as a number in Azure's mobileApp tool, I do believe it is converted to a Numeric under the hood though. 2. My EndDate is a number because I'm storing it as an offset since a certain day(similar to a JulianDay - [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day)) 3. I've tried messing around with the capitalization and have matched it, no luck though 4. Payout isn't supposed to be a number as it could be a user entered task

Comment: Try searching for the error you found with relation to Azure Mobile App tool- here's a result which might give you some idea: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/06b9952b-2c23-4af3-b5aa-b2cca73bd90d/error-converting-data-type-nvarchar-to-numeric?forum=vbgeneral

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether the model is from the server or client.  Looking at the model:

1. On the client, you should not have a deleted column
2. The createdAt / updatedAt should be "DateTimeOffset?" type (? is to allow nullable)
3. The version should be byte[] type
4. ID should be Id (capitalization matters)
5. If this is a server-side model, then you should inherit from EntityData rather than including the CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, ID, Deleted and Version fields.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, updated original to say that it is client side. None of those fixes worked though, any other ideas? Again, the actual insert into the table is working but getting the data back isn't working.

Comment: Can you update the code you provided with the changes you made?  SInce it is a client-side mode, #1-#4 matter.

Comment: Also, please add the Server-Side DTO model

Comment: I believe your table (and models) are using the wrong thing for createdAt and updatedAt.  - the type in the models should be DateTimeOffset? and the table should show DATETIMEOFFSET(7).  This makes me think that you are not inheriting from EntityData on the server, which should definitely be done.  In addition, ensure the system property triggers are being created.  If they aren't you have a problem in your server-side code.

Comment: As I stated, I'm using an Azure Mobile app on the backend so I'm pretty certain the issue doesn't exist on the backend

Comment: @Daniel Are you using Easy Tables on the backend, or do you have a .NET project?

Comment: I'm using the Easy Tables